# Energy dissipation in a circuit with only capacitors

Tags: capacitor, energy, dissipation

**Context**:
Consider a circuit with only two linear time invariant capacitors. If I charge one the capacitors and then throw a switch that closes the circuit, there will be some redistribution of charge. The capacitors are ideal and there is no resistance in the circuit.

**Problem**

I calculated the energy before the circuit was closed and after the circuit attained a steady state. There was some energy dissipation.

My question is: In what form is the dissipated energy leaving the circuit?

Comment: I had a look at the question and the answers however i did not find an answer to my question, which was pertaining to the form in which energy was released by the circuit under ideal conditions (I believe i did mention there are no resistances)

Comment: [This answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/75456/decrease-in-stored-energy-after-connection-of-another-capacitor/75490#75490) doesn't satisfy you?

Comment: profuse apologies for not doing my homework before asking a question here... @brhans the answer did satisfy me, i overlooked the second answer to that question

Comment: The infinite current in the zero ohm resistances tends to account for the losses :-) . | Congratulations on apologising due to an oversight - it's rare. (+1 :-) ).