# PCB analog and digital split impossible with multiplexers?

Tags: pcb, digital-logic, analog

I'm trying to make a PCB that has both an analog part and digital part.

I divided the PCB in areas (sort of), like power supply, MCU (STM32), multiplexers (around 10 ICs, mix of CD4051s, CD4052's and CD4053), and analog components (mostly transistors and capacitors for audio signals).

I know it is advised to keep the analog part away from the digital part, but the multiplexers define all the (flexible) audio routing, so it's impossible to split the PCB in an analog and digital part as all multiplexer ICs handle both digital (the selection of channels) and analog (the channels themselves).

Below is my 'work in progress'... Most ICs are multiplexers (although I want to keep the digital only ICs on the right side, such as shift registers and level shifters).
... and yes, I know I have to move some ICs as they are off the edge now :-)

[image]

How can I make sure there will be no noise/crosstalk?

Some ideas I gathered/read about:

- Using GND for back (impossible to split in a digital GND and analog GND though)
- No parallel digital next to analog signals (also hard, as I use the Manhattan technique, otherwise routing is impossible)
- Using GND signals parallel to analog signals (not tried, but cost quite some space to have many parallel signals).
- Putting all analog components on one side of the board (not tried, is this a good idea?); not sure how to handle GND in a good manner this way.
- Or should I try to separate the board in a digital/analog part, and get long lines from the multiplexers to the analog components and carefully route each multiplexer to minimize crossing digital/analog traces?

Note, I'm mainly using SMD components, and my electronics (as a hobby) skills are not good enough I can do a noise analysis (if there exists such thing practically).

Any better ideas are welcome.

**Update**

Possibly there is not much of an issue, since the multiplexers only change when the users presses a button (which results in a change of all settings, but this is once per 100 ms in worst case.

So the most 'worry' is that 9V signals (for controlling the multiplexers) close to a (much lower?) audio/analog signal can affect that analog signal. I think not, but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: Keep the digital edges as slow as you need them, add a resistor on every digital output that has to cross a significant part of the PCB (resistor arrays are your friends in these cases).

Comment: @WesleyLee I'm afraid I need a bit more info ... how can I keep them slow? I can lower the SPI speed if that's what you mean (but that doesn't make the edges slower I think).

Comment: @WesleyLee  And I'm not sure how to use resistor arrays in this case ... afaik they have one single output... or do you mean resistor arrays which have many resistors (with two sides for every resistor... didn't know those exist)... And also than, adding a resistor will change the output, so I'm not sure what result that will give. Currently I have to use level shifters to 9V as the analog signals are 9V and driving the multiplexers with less will not work.

Comment: He is not saying that you need to slow down your clock frequency but the rise/fall time of the clock edge. Even a slow clock, with fast rising edges has multiple harmonics that can couple onto other signals. Series resistors help slow down the edges, if you can afford that.

Comment: @Big6 Ok thanks for the clarification ... Maybe in my case it's less important anyway as the multiplexers do not change often ... or is having a 9V (continuous) signal close to an audio signal (lower power) also problematic? Only the SPI clock I have to keep away.

Comment: Another thing that helps, aside from routing itself, is having the signal and its reference layer/plane as close as possible. Everything being equal, it reduces crosstalk. There is a page by Henry Ott that goes into the details. Here is that link: http://www.hottconsultants.com/techtips/pcb-stack-up-2.html

Comment: I will read it, thanks for the link (edited after you added the link)

Comment: @Big6 THanks for the link, but I stick with a 2 layer board (due to cost mainly). But good to know when I in the future will have some higher frequency or critical boards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Series resistors:

They are series termination resistors, close to the source of the signal. They won't reduce the data rate of your signal, will just make their rise/fall time longer (slower edges).

There are some quick references to this by [Henry Ott](http://www.hottconsultants.com/pdf_files/pcb_guide.pdf), and this video by [Robert Feranec](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UbQjOApEe3k), and some detailed explanation in [this EE.SE question/answers](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/195616/why-is-it-good-to-slow-down-digital-lines-with-resistors), so I won't go into too much detail.

But basically, the faster your signal changes on a line, more noise its gonna induce around it.

Resistor arrays:

I like [YC164](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/447/PYu-YC_TC_group_51_RoHS_L_7-1313905.pdf), which are easy-ish to hand solder or place manually on pasted PCBs. But basically they are a space saving and "part count reducer" if you are soldering stuff by hand.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRmgql.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thanks ... I will read into it (tomorrow as it's late now). It's a good task for me to find out what the resistor value should be... I didn't know these existed. I know SIP network arrays, but they have a common 'GND', these are like multiple resistors in one, more useful.

Comment: You don't have to use a resistor array, it is just something that is super helpful if you have to add a bunch of resistors of the same values all next to each other. Also, there are a bunch of crosstalk calculators online (i.e. you input rise/fall times and the distance/geometry of the tracks, and it will give you an estimated crosstalk, so that could be a decent ballpark to start with). Alternatively, for one off projects and/or slow-ish data rates, you can just add a resistor and change later empirically. (i.e. check the signals and crosstalk with a scope).

Comment: @MichelKeijzers - Thanks but please don't accept my answer yet as there might be other helpful answers, I just posted this to complement my comment.

Comment: Thanks for all those tips ... it's indeed a one-off project (or a zero-off if I run into more problems ;-)  ) ... actually it's more a learning experiment (and hope to make someone else happy with a possible result). And adding resistors also make it indeed possible to use a scope (I have one).

Comment: Ok (but probably I accept it later) ... maybe in my case it's not even that much of an issue (the crosstalk for edges), as when the settings are changed (and the multiplexers are changing), the sound (going through the analog traces) is high likely off anyway. And I think having a 9V (continuous) signal next to a (changing) low voltage audio signal is no problem. I should check that, as I also have a wave form generator. Really need to get used to the tools I have since some time ;-) Although I don't have a PCB with traces to check.

Comment: I read through all of it (didn't understand it fully), but at least I have some better guidelines. According to Robert (I like his videos), they are used to timing signals, so I'm planning to do (as the other signals don't change often anyway).