# First-Order Lowpass RC Filter

Tags: circuit-analysis, filter, circuit-design, bode-plot, passive-filter

The figure below is from Analog-Digital Interface Integrated Circuits course [here](http://www-inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~ee247/fa10/files07/lectures/L1_f10_2.pdf) (page 14/25).

I am curious about the red question in the picture below. From the Bode plot, the answer would be yes. But I don't think it is correct here. The professor may want to talk about something else.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's all about recognizing the reality of parasitic components.

For instance, an 0603 style resistor might have an equivalent parasitic parallel capacitance of 0.2 pF (in situ on a PCB). At high frequencies, this will form an AC potential divider with C1 (10 pF) and, in terms of attenuation, is ~0.02 or, -34 dB and nowhere near -100 dB as would be implied if the parasitic capacitance of the resistor were ignored.

You can also argue that the parasitic series inductance of the 10 pF capacitor makes it less than ideal and this also makes the attenuation of 100 dB very unreasonable. All in all when you get much above several hundreds of MHz you cannot expect the sort of performance you'd get at audio frequencies.

Comment: Thanks. Thank makes sense. I have just the following lecture and it actually implies about parasitic as you said.

Comment: OK glad to assist. Don't formally accept the answer just yet, leave it a day or so to allow other folk to share their thoughts. I see you have never formally accepted any answers to your questions and that surprises me!

Comment: Yes, I like to read other opinion too. Sometimes, I also feel bad not to accept a good answer. However, with answers really solve my problem, I am happy to accept it.

Comment: Don't feel bad - if an answer helps or corrects you then it deserves accepting, for instance this one... http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/267380/initial-input-current-of-voltage-inverter. Look at accepting answers as the price for getting good advice.